# What does "taking mock offence" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases

What does "taking mock offence" mean? It is said in brackets in a play as a kind of comment how the character behaves or says the following words.

I can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pretending to take offense, probably in a dramatic, over-emphasized way. "What!? You didn't accept my answer on StackExchange?! I'm Shocked! Shocked I tell You!"

Answer (score 5):

[Mock](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/mock) in this context refers to the "counterfeit" meaning, rather than the "insulting through mimicry" meaning.  This means that the player is only pretending to be offended, but is not really angry or upset; he is "mocking" or faking taking offense.

Comment: Something Kit is mighty able at... :)

Comment: @Third Idiot Who me? *blinks innocently*

Comment: "Mock" as an adjective always has this meaning: the verb has the other meaning.

Answer (score 4):

"Taking mock offense" is the same as "pretending to take offense".  Note that the pretending should often be *apparent*; that is, person who "offended" would not normally believe they had offended anyone.

Answer (score 3):

Mock offense equates to feigned outrage.  Examples are easily observable on a regular basis by anyone who tunes in to the venomous ranting and raving of political partisans on radio & TV, all day every day, up & down the dial.